# WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: sql, wordpress

I am facing this error.

    WordPress database error 
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 for query

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_author_favorite 
WHERE post_id = 1743 
AND author_id = made by require('D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\engeniuspark.in\sos.engeniuspark.in\wp-blog-header.php'), 
require_once('D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\engeniuspark.in\sos.engeniuspark.in\wp-includes\template-loader.php'), 
include('D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\engeniuspark.in\sos.engeniuspark.in\wp-content\themes\theme-name\single.php'), 
wp_authors_favorite_check
```

Comment: you have a where clause that is not receiving any input, your author_id= is not being filled in

Answer (score 0):

You need to give `AND author_id =` a value

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_author_favorite 
WHERE post_id = 1743 
AND author_id = 1234 /*For example*/
made by require('D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\engeniuspark.in\sos.engeniuspark.in\wp-blog-header.php'), 
require_once('D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\engeniuspark.in\sos.engeniuspark.in\wp-includes\template-loader.php'), 
include('D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\engeniuspark.in\sos.engeniuspark.in\wp-content\themes\theme-name\single.php'), 
wp_authors_favorite_check
```